# Jboss: EL expression in JSP doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I am running Jboss EAP 6.3.
I have this form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>registrationPage.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to JBoss!</h1>

<div>
    <p>You have successfully deployed a Java EE 6 web
        application.</p>
</div>

<form id="reg" action="register.do" method="POST">
    <h2>Member Registration</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="name">Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id=name name="name"
                       value="${newMember.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="email">Email:</label>
            </td>

            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email"
                       value="${newMember.email}" /> <!-- <h:message  for="email" errorClass="invalid" />-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><label
                    for="phoneNumber">Phone #:</label></td>
            <td><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"
                       type="text" value="${newMember.phoneNumber}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label style="color: green;width: 100%;text-align: left;">${infoMessage}</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label style="color: red; width: 100%;text-align: left;">${errorMessage}</label>
    </p>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

I am pretty sure I didn't change anything since yesterday, but today I woke up and it now looks like this:

[image]

There are no errors as far as I can see.

Comment: Please post the controller code that calls resolves to this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been solved by adding

```
isELIgnored="false"
```

to the page.
Like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"   isELIgnored="false"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Apparently EL expressions are ignored by default and you have to manually enable them.

Answer (score 1):

At first check that you have filled up the object "newMember" appropriately before loading this page. Then you can use the following process to show data in your view:

1. At first use this line top of your view page:

   **<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>**
2. Then use the following process for your table, showing on the view. Here I have only shown the changes:

   ```
   <td><input type="text" id=name name="name"
              value='<c:out value="${newMember.name}"></c:out>'/>
   </td>

   <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email"
              value='<c:out value="${newMember.email}"></c:out>'/> 
   </td>

   <td><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" type="text" 
       value='<c:out value="${newMember.phoneNumber}"></c:out>'/>
   ```

3.I think it's a better process to show data in a view.